# Не работают виртуальные хосты XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, сервер, xampp, virtual-hosts

Работаю с XAMPP. Я хотел настроить виртуальный хост для своего проекта.

1. Прописал в `hosts`:
   `127.0.0.1 lovea.ua`
2. Прописал в `httpd-vhosts` следующее:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lovea.ua
    DocumentRoot "Z:/Programming/XAMPP/htdocs/lovea.ua"
    ServerName lovea.ua
    ServerAlias www.lovea.ua
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Перезапустил сервера.
4. Зашёл по адресу `lovea.ua` и у меня открылось содержимое папки `htdocs`. То есть `lovea.ua` теперь ссылается туда, куда до этого ссылался `localhost`.
5. Зашёл по адресу `localhost` и, не поверите, там открылся мой проект, который лежит в `htdocs/lovea.ua`.

Я вообще не понял, как это возможно, поэтому прошу помощи.

Мне надо, чтобы `localhost` ссылался, куда и всегда - в папку `htdocs`, а `lovea.ua` открывал мой проект в папке `htdocs/lovea.ua`.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

в файле `c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` прописал следующее:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/sites/t"
    ServerName m.lk
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

В `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` - `127.0.0.1 m.lk`.

Поведение такое, как вы хотите.

С алиасами и логами не заморачивался, думаю, там проблем не будет.

Comment: `localhost` и правда теперь ссылается на `htdocs`, но когда я пытаюсь зайти по своему адресу, мне тоже по-прежнему выдаёт `htdocs`.

https://imgur.com/a/4xFTYSG

Comment: Мои файлы `vhosts` и `hosts`: https://imgur.com/a/TUUp1A2

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost  в hosts у меня нету. Только 127.0.0.1 m.lk.

Comment: `localhost` в `hosts` ни на что не влияет

Comment: Я тож так думаю, просто написал, что у меня .